# How to Generate Id for newly inserted records in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

**My Code:**

```
// Check if Record ID exists
        $RecordExists = $recordss->findOne(intval($item['id']));
        if($recordExists){
            if($this->confirm("Record ID: ${item['id']} already exists. Overwrite?")){
                $this->printOutput('Overwriting existing record', 'plain');
                $records = $recordExists;
                $version = RecordsSearch::findVersionOfRecord($recordExists->getPrimaryKey()) + 1;

            }
            else{
                $this->printOutput('Not overwriting existing record. Exiting now!', 'error', True);
            }
        }
        else{
            // Record ID does not exists, so we set record ID
            $records->id = $item['id'];
            $version = 1;
        }
```

The Above Code is used in an Yii command function.

**What the code does ?**

The above code handles json importing of certain records.When the record from json file is imported it generates an new record if the ID doesnot exist.
But if the ID exist's it asks to overwrite.

**What i need?**

The Requirement i have is that when a new record is imported from JSON with a ID that already exists in the DB it asks to overwrite.Instead i need the record to be imported and ID to be generated automatically.How can i implement this ?

Recommendation for the ID's to be changed in JSON is not really an option for me here.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: it is hard to understand what you are asking are you saying that in case the id is found yo need to insert a new record and that too with an autoincremented id rather than the `ID` coming from `json` file.

Comment: Yes exactly.!!!

Comment: then just remove the `$records->id = $item['id'];` you dont need this line make sure you have set your `id` field as primary key and `auto-increment` it will assign the id itself.